# how load the url with + character in webview using postdata?

Tags: android, post, webview

I try to load the url using webview, but I faced the one problem with + character in the credentials, because + character convert as space, so the request fails.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You should encode the request params

Comment: if you use the encode request parameter then use the EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64")

Comment: Im using

myWebView.postUrl(URL_LOGIN_TEST, EncodingUtils.getBytes(buildPostData(email, password), "base64"));

Comment: @Rego what is buildPostData.? why use this. you use like.String creditionationString=username="test&"+password="test" then apply the encode om them.. your way is rong..

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh its a string builder function.

Comment: @Rego before your url use the like my answer it's work for you.. just try dude

Comment: Ive been using it @ZalaJanaksinh same way. Its already my original code.

Comment: @Rego then sorry bro provide some code block because it's complete work for me.

Comment: myWebView.postUrl(URL_LOGIN_TEST, EncodingUtils.getBytes(buildPostData(email, password), "BASE64"));

Comment: private String buildPostData(String email, String password) {

        String postData = "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password +  "&" + "mobile-flag=1" + "&" + "device_type=3"
        + "&" + "hwid=" + uid;
        Log.d("JOSH", " POSTDATA " +postData);
        return postData;
    }

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh there bro thanks

Comment: Already did, same result

Answer (score 0):

I think you use your username & password like this.

```
String postData = "username=test&password=test";
webPurchaseBalance.postUrl(YOUR_URL, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        postData = "email=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")
        +"&" + "password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
```

Hi here is how I made it work, you need to use URLEncoder.encode then use Zala's answer above when doing post.